# How to check checkbox when there is an array in React Native?

Tags: react-native, checkbox, mapping

I want to get checked friends using checkbox. But I not quite sure how i will achieve it, hope someone can help me.

**This is my state:**

```
state = {checked: false}
```

**This is where I want to map array**

```
{this.props.navigation.getParam('friends').map((name, key) => (
<View>
  <Text>{name}</Text>
  <CheckBox 
    checked={this.state.checked}
    onPress={(val)=>{}}
  />
</View>))}
```

*Note:* Or Could someone write me an app/code snippet in snack.expo.io how to get only checked checkbox value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom checkbox component

```
    export default class CustomCheckbox extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          checked: false,
        };
      }
      toggleChange(){
        this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked});
      }
      render() {
        return (
         <View>
      <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      <CheckBox 
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onPress={() =>  this.bind.toggleChange(this)}
      />
    </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

and import your CustomCheckbox component

```
    import CustomCheckbox from "your CustomCheckbox.js path"

    {this.props.navigation.getParam('friends').map((name, key) => (
    <View>
      <CustomCheckbox name={name} />
    </View>
    ))}
```

Comment: it says: `undefined is not an object ('evaluating _this2.bind.toggleChange')`

Comment: <actually it works, I just rewrite `onPress={()=> this.toggleChange()}` Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty good to go, you just need to update a bit. You have following two options:

Your friend's array should have checked key within each containing object, then you can simply do something like this.

```
{
this.props.navigation.getParam('friends').map((item, key) => (
let {name, checked} = item // item is an object from friends array,the  and it have name, checked and other keys
<View>
  <Text>{name}</Text>
  <CheckBox 
    checked={checked}
    onPress={(val)=>{}}
  />
</View>))
}
```

Other is you to save the name of the person as key and true/false as the checked state, eg :

```
toggleCurrentFirendState = (item)=>{
   this.setState((prevState)=>{
       let {name} = item  //get name from clicked friend from the list
       return {
           ...prevState,  //used spread operator, so that other states doesn't get mutat.
          [name]:!prevState[name] //toogle state of clicked item
       }
   })
}

//within your render
{
this.props.navigation.getParam('friends').map((item, key) => (
let {name} = item // item is an object from friends array,the  and it have name, checked and other keys
<View>
  <Text>{name}</Text>
  <CheckBox 
    checked={name ===this.state[name]}  //see change
    onPress={(val)=>{this.toggleCurrentFirendState(item)}}
  />
</View>))
}
```

Comment: parsing error: unexpected token on:  let {name} = item

Comment: try to console.log(item) before that line

Comment: console shows friend names, it means item has value

Comment: okay maybe, you are on ES5, replace let {name} with var name = item.name

Comment: I am writing on snack.expo.io

Comment: share the link of snack, you are working on, will try to check

Comment: components/AddBill.js

Comment: could you also please write a method which filters checked items, thanks

Comment: you just need to loop through the array and filter the checked element, I was not able to run that snack but I removed the errors

Comment: Thanks for trying. You are kind to help